# What are the future imperatives of sum?

Tags: classical-latin, verbs, conjugation

I have a book: *501 Latin Verbs: fully conjugated*. In the conjugations for the verb sum, it leaves out the future imperatives. Are there no future imperatives for sum? So how would, "You must be *noun/adjective* by *time or condition*" translate?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

There certainly is a future imperative of *esse* in Latin: see Allen and Greenough's [New Latin Grammar](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus:text:1999.04.0001:part=1:section=25&highlight=):

```
IMPERATIVE

PRESENT SING.   2. ĕs, be thou  PLUR.       2. este, be ye
FUTURE          2. estō, thou shalt be      2. estōte, ye shall be
                3. estō, he shall be        3. suntō, they shall be
```

I have never met *sunto* in casual reading, though it often appears (per C.M. Weimer's comment) in legal contexts. Here is a classical example:

> *regio imperio duo sunto* (Cic. de Legg. iii. 4)
>
> There shall be two [consuls] for the royal empire.

In my reading, *esto* and *estote* appear more frequently. See, for example, an example from the Vulgate:

> *estote ergo vos perfecti sicut et Pater vester caelestis perfectus est* (Matt 5:48)
>
> Be ye therefore perfect as your heavenly Father is perfect.

The future imperatives are not the most common forms for necessity: in the example you give of "must," I would suggest translating with a *passive periphrastic*, e.g. *legendum est tibi* = *you should read*

Comment: You see *sunto* all over legal documents, like the [Twelve Tables](http://www.orbilat.com/Languages/Latin/Texts/01_Preliterary_period/12_Tables.htm).

Answer (score 6):

The answer @brianpck gives is exactly right. However, the future imperative wouldn't work for your sentence, because the future imperative is used to describe long-lasting or permanent states, as in both his examples. If you were Minerva warning Paris against giving the Apple of Discord to the wrong goddess, you'd say (understanding that for *esse* the present subjunctive is usually substituted for the present imperative):

> Probus sis!
>   Be good!

But if you were Ulysses leaving home knowing that this might be your last chance for a few decades to give Telemachus advice, you'd say

> Probus esto!
>   Be good!

For your example I'd probably use either the present subjunctive plus the subjunctive in a fear clause:

> Cras adsis ne moriaris!
>   Be there tomorrow, lest you die!

or a future more vivid condition:

> Si cras non aderis, morieris.
>   If you're not there tomorrow, you will die.

Cato also uses the future imperative as how-to instructions in *De Agricultura* (wash your hands, salt the meat, etc.), but I've read neither any other Cato nor any other how-to instructions, so I don't know how universal that is.