# Imperative of sum - es or esto?

Tags: imperative, esse

The imperatives of sum/esse (to be) are **sg.** es/esto and **pl.** este.

When do we use es? And when esto?

Comment: Related: [What are the future imperatives of sum?](https://latin.stackexchange.com/questions/565/what-are-the-future-imperatives-of-sum)

Comment: But this is the present.

Comment: Could you clarify where you are seeing *esto* given as a present imperative form of *sum*? Allen and Greenough describe it as a future imperative *form* even when used with a generic meaning: [449](http://dcc.dickinson.edu/grammar/latin/imperative) (giving the example "Is iūris cīvīlis cūstōs estō. (Legg. 3.8) Let him (the prætor) be the guardian of civil right.")

Comment: I was taught this by my teacher, based off the Oxford Latin Course

Comment: It's possible that you may have misunderstood: i.e. that it wasn't explicitly said that *esto* was present tense, but you assumed it.

Answer (score 6):

*Es* and *este* are the present imperative, *esto* and *estote* are the future imperative.
As far as I know, the difference between present and future imperatives is the same for all verbs, and *esse* is not different.

I think the general differences between present and future imperatives should be asked in a separate question — if not asked already.
It is not simply a matter of tense but there are nuances to it.

(The present imperative only has the second person forms.
The future one has these and third person forms *esto* (same as second) and *sunto*.
This is the same for all verbs.)

Comment: If I recall correctly, *esto* not infrequently occurs in the function of a present imperative, simply because *es* shares its form with the indicative and therefore introduces a not insignificant amount of ambiguity.

Comment: @Anonym Makes sense! If you can quote a grammar and an example or two where such ambiguity would arise if *es* were used, it'd make a great answer.